# Azure Function V3 Dependency Injection Lifetime Question

Tags: dependency-injection, azure-functions, azure-function-app

I am using Azure Functions v3 and DI.  I have a service that I setup with a transient lifetime in my StartUp.cs (using: `builder.Services.AddTransient<ICoreApiClient>(s => coreApiService);`) and then I inject into my Azure Function class.  The Azure Function is a Storage Queue trigger function.

I expect that for each queue message I will get a separate instance of my "coreApiService" but I seem to be sharing one instance when multiple messages are put in the queue at the same time.

Is my expectation to get a separate instance for each invocation or "Run" incorrect?
The issue I am running into is that the "_coreApiClient" seems to be shared between multiple invocations of the Run method so as I set properties within it (like "Customer ID" or "API Key", etc.) that I are valid for one message and should remain for the processing of that message are changing as it starts processing the next message.

Am I doing it wrong or do I not understand the lifetime properly?

Here is my startup code:

```
public class Startup: FunctionsStartup
    {
        public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Services.AddLogging();
            
            var loggingService = new HttpLoggingService(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("LoggingURL"), 0, "ABC.Integrations");
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ILoggingService>(s => loggingService);

            int CoreApiTimeout = 60;  //Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CoreApiTimeout")
            var coreApiService = new CoreApiClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CoreApiKey"),string.Empty, CoreApiTimeout,Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CoreApiBaseUrl"));
            builder.Services.AddTransient<ICoreApiClient>(s => coreApiService);
           
        }
    }
```

And my Azure Function class:

```
public class TaskRouter
    {
        private readonly ICoreApiClient _coreApiClient;
        private readonly ILoggingService _upgLogger;
        private readonly ILogger<TaskRouter> _log;        

        public TaskRouter(ICoreApiClient coreApiClient, ILoggingService upgLogger, ILogger<TaskRouter> log)
        {
            _coreApiClient = coreApiClient;
            _upgLogger = upgLogger;
            _log = log;
            
        }

        [FunctionName("RouteTask")]
        [ExponentialBackoffRetry(5, "00:00:04", "00:03:00")]
        public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("task-scheduler", Connection = "")]
            string queueItem)
        {

            
                //Call Appropriate Function to start task
                var taskMsg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TaskMessage>(queueItem);
                                
                _coreApiClient.SetId(taskMsg.TaskNumber);
                
                //DO SOME WORK HERE
                
                Console.Log(_coreApiClient.GetId);  //Will be different b/c this was set by the next message
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the client is registered as transient with the container, it is actually a singleton since the instance created in Startup is the only instance that will ever be returned for each call to inject `ICoreApiClient`.

Move the instance creation into the factory delegate, making this an actual transient registration, so that a new instance will be initialized each time `ICoreApiClient` has to be resolved from the service provider.

```
//...

builder.Services.AddTransient<ICoreApiClient>(s => 
    new CoreApiClient(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CoreApiKey"), string.Empty, CoreApiTimeout, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CoreApiBaseUrl"))
);

//...
```

Comment: Ah, thank you so much - that was the issue.  Very logical and seems obvious in hindsight but I looked at this for hours and did not realize that.  Thank you!!