# What is the ServiceLifetime of IServiceProvider in a Time Trigger Azure Functions

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-functions

I am observing that the `hashCode` of `_serviceProvider`  is the same throughout all the execution of the below function at an interval of 1 min.

```cs
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System;

namespace TestFunction
{
    public class Function2
    {
        private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
        public Function2(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        }

        [FunctionName("Function2")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            var hashCode = _serviceProvider.GetHashCode();
            log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
        }
    }
}
```

**Version:**

```
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
```

**FYI:** I also compared the `hashcode` of serviceProvider in an `API` for two requests at the same endpoint but they are different.

**Question:** What is the lifetime of IServiceProvider in a Time Trigger Azure Functions?

Comment: As you are using timer trigger `TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")` it should return in 1 minute of interval time . Also could you please refer this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#use-injected-dependencies)

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT My main purpose is to figure out the lifetime of the service provider here.

Comment: There are different types of service provider like Based on the above given document: Transient,scoped&Singleton . Could you please confirm me is this the same you are looking for [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#service-lifetimes)

Comment: Yes. @AjayKumarGhose-MT

Comment: Sorry, your answer doesn't confirm with proof that what is the lifetime of the IServiceProvider in respect to azure function. @AjayKumarGhose-MT

Comment: Please complete your question: you start by saying what you are trying, but you don't report your findings. And the question should also be stated in the body, not only in the title.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @akash, For the update.

Based on this [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection#service-lifetimes):

> For a Functions app, the different service lifetimes behave as
> follows:
>
> **Transient**: Transient services are created upon each resolution of the service.
>
> **Scoped**: The scoped service lifetime matches a function execution lifetime. Scoped services are created once per function execution.
> Later requests for that service during the execution reuse the
> existing service instance.
>
> **Singleton**: The singleton service lifetime matches the host lifetime and is reused across function executions on that instance.
> Singleton lifetime services are recommended for connections and
> clients, for example DocumentClient or HttpClient instances.
>
> View or download a [sample of different service
> lifetimes](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-dotnet-extensions/tree/main/src/samples/DependencyInjection/Scopes)
> on GitHub.

For more information please refer the below links:

SO THREAD : [Azure Function V3 Dependency Injection Lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66412416/azure-function-v3-dependency-injection-lifetime-question)

BLOG: [Dependency Injection in Azure Functions](https://www.serverless360.com/blog/dependency-injection-in-azure-functions)

Comment: Really sorry that your answer doesn't confirm with proof that what is the lifetime of the IServiceProvider in respect to azure function. @AjayKumarGhose-MT.

Answer (score 0):

[IServiceProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider) is just an interface for the service collection. But it's implemented by e.g. [HttpContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext) used in ASP.NET. HttpContext has a lifetime of a request, i.e. it is Scoped.

Comment: Yes, It is scoped in API.